# is there way to apply row updates without looping

Tags: sql, t-sql

i would like to pay for different invoices using different credits i have.

```
drop table #InvoicesWithBalances
drop table #AvailableCredits
create table #InvoicesWithBalances
(
InvoiceKey decimal(18,0) not null,
APBalance decimal(18,6) null,
BalanceAfterCreditApplied decimal(18,6) null,

)
create table #AvailableCredits
(
credit_id int identity(1,1),
StartingBalance decimal(18,6) null,
CurrentBalance decimal(18,6) null,

)

insert into #InvoicesWithBalances values (5452, 13744.080000, 13744.080000)
insert into #InvoicesWithBalances values (7056, 13744.080000, 13744.080000)
insert into #InvoicesWithBalances values (7438, 500.000000, 500.000000 )
insert into #AvailableCredits values ( -13744.080000, -13744.080000)
insert into #AvailableCredits values ( -13700.080000, -13700.080000)
insert into #AvailableCredits values ( -500.000000, -500.000000)
insert into #AvailableCredits values ( -500.000000, -500.000000)


select * from #InvoicesWithBalances

select * from #AvailableCredits
```

If I was doing a looping solution I would take the largest credit and start applying it to the invoices in order of largest to smallest until the balance of the credit is zero, then I would move on to the next to the next credit until I had no credits and no invoices left.
In the example below the first 2 credits should be fully used.  The third credit should be partially used and the last credit should go untouched
Any advice?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: Searching for [`[tsql] depleting`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btsql%5D+depleting) may provide some clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to simulate your example here:

```
create table InvoicesWithBalances
(
InvoiceKey int not null,
APBalance int null,
BalanceAfterCreditApplied int null,

);
create table AvailableCredits
(
credit_id int identity(1,1),
StartingBalance int null,
CurrentBalance int null,

);

insert into InvoicesWithBalances values (5452, 13744, 13744);
insert into InvoicesWithBalances values (7056, 13744, 13744);
insert into InvoicesWithBalances values (7438, 500, 500);
insert into AvailableCredits values ( -13744, -13744);
insert into AvailableCredits values ( -13700, -13700);
insert into AvailableCredits values ( -500, -500);
insert into AvailableCredits values ( -500, -500);

create table #invoice (invoice_row_num int, InvoiceKey int, APBalance int, BalanceAfterCreditApplied int);

insert into #invoice 
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY APBalance desc) as row_num, InvoiceKey, APBalance, BalanceAfterCreditApplied FROM InvoicesWithBalances;


create table #credits (credit_row_num int, StartingBalance int, CurrentBalance int);

insert into #credits
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartingBalance asc) as row_num, StartingBalance, CurrentBalance FROM AvailableCredits;

create table #invoice_credit_list (invoice_credit_row_num int, init_invoice int, init_credit int);

if ((select max(invoice_row_num) from #invoice) > (select max(credit_row_num) from #credits))

    insert into #invoice_credit_list
      select i.invoice_row_num , i.APBalance, (-isnull(c.StartingBalance,0)) from 
      #invoice i
      left join 
      #credits c
      on 
      i.invoice_row_num = c.credit_row_num;
else
     insert into #invoice_credit_list
      select c.credit_row_num, isnull(i.APBalance,0), (-c.StartingBalance) from 
      #credits c
      left join 
      #invoice i
      on 
      i.invoice_row_num = c.credit_row_num;




with cte as
(
    select 
    invoice_credit_row_num,
    init_invoice,
    init_credit,
    case when  init_invoice >= init_credit then
         init_invoice - init_credit
         else
         0
         end as 'invoice_remaining',
    case when  init_credit >= init_invoice then
         init_credit - init_invoice
         else
         0
         end as 'credit_remaining'
    from
    #invoice_credit_list i
    where
    i.invoice_credit_row_num = 1

    UNION ALL

    select 
    i.invoice_credit_row_num,
    i.init_invoice + cte.invoice_remaining as 'init_invoice',
    i.init_credit + cte.credit_remaining as 'init credit',
    case when  (i.init_invoice + cte.invoice_remaining) >= (i.init_credit + cte.credit_remaining ) then
         (i.init_invoice + cte.invoice_remaining) - (i.init_credit + cte.credit_remaining )
         else
         0
         end as 'invoice_remaining',
    case when (i.init_credit + cte.credit_remaining) >= (i.init_invoice + cte.invoice_remaining) then
         (i.init_credit + cte.credit_remaining) - (i.init_invoice + cte.invoice_remaining)
         else
         0
         end as 'credit_remaining'
    from
    #invoice_credit_list i
    inner join
    cte
    ON
    i.invoice_credit_row_num - 1 = cte.invoice_credit_row_num
    AND
    i.invoice_credit_row_num > 1


)
select * from cte;
```

and you can also find this simulation with output here: https://rextester.com/SJYGV76640

The 'cte' table in the simulation will give you all the details.

Eventhough, this is now done in db side, I am not sure of its performance. So, please compare and evaluate its performance.

Note:

1. if this is performing faster, well and good. But, at most, don't opt for loops in T-SQL.
2. If this is not performing better, go for loops in any other programming language like C#, VB,.. if that is possible.
3. If no other option works for you, go for loops in T-SQL. But, with increasing data, I am not sure how the server will react :(

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: could you please share which of the three options worked faster for you?